# Is this degrees of freedom calculation from McCullagh and Nelder wrong?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

This is a question regarding the Generalized Linear Models book of Mccullough and Nelder. It's available [here](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/oldclass/2201s11/readings/glmbook.pdf). Starting on page 204 there is an example regarding shipping incidents; one of the conclusions from fitting a model with interactions is

> There is inconclusive evidence of an interaction between ship type and
>   year of construction, the deviance being reduced from 38.7 with 25
>   degrees of freedom to 14.6 with 10.

The 25 degrees of freedom is obtained from $34$ observations with $1 + (5 - 1) + (4 - 1) + (2 - 1) = 9$ parameters. My issue is that the interaction term has 5 levels for one factor and 4 levels for the other, meaning it should account for $(5 - 1) \cdot (4 - 1) = 12$ degrees of freedom, so we should go from 25 degrees of freedom to 13. You only get 10 degrees of freedom if you do $5 \cdot 3 = 15$ parameters for the interactions. Am I missing something obvious here?

**EDIT**: Added a simulation, which is just adding to my confusion.

```
X <- expand.grid(1:5, 1:4, 1:2)
idx_0 <- c(7,15,23,31,34,39)
X <- X[-idx_0,]

f <- function() {
  ## Simulate from the null model. The value 10.5 is the mean number of
  ## incidents for the actual ship data

  Y <- apply(X, 1, function(row) rpois(1,10.5))
  fit_Y <- glm(Y ~ as.factor(X[,1]) * as.factor(X[,2]) + as.factor(X[,3]), 
               family = poisson)  
  deviance(fit_Y)
}

set.seed(1234)
foo <- replicate(10000, f())

plot(ecdf(foo))
xlim <- c(0, max(foo))
plot(function(x) pchisq(x, 13), add = TRUE, col = 'forestgreen', lwd = 3, 
     from = xlim[1], to = xlim[2])
plot(function(x) pchisq(x, 10), add = TRUE, col = 'dodgerblue3', lwd = 3, 
     from = xlim[1], to = xlim[2])
```

Comment: The answer to your question begins on the bottom of page 207 of the text and concludes on the next page.

Comment: @Adam0 Can you explain what I am doing wrong in my newly added bootstrap simulation? Because simulating from the null model really seems to suggest to me that 13 degrees of freedom is accurate. I don't really follow M+N's reasoning on conditioning on why I should be conditioning on a sufficient statistic.

Comment: @AdamO accidentally tagged you as Adam0 in my last comment, so adding another comment to make sure you are pinged.